# linear layouts not spacing correctly

Tags: android, xml, layout

Hey im having trouble with these linear layouts in android xml.  initially i did them in a relative layout and it worked fine, but after some research i discovered that relative layouts inside of a scrollview doesnt work supposedly.  so now after much tweaking my imageview shows up but has a huge margin above and below it and my textview doesnt even show up aside from being where its supposed to in the graphics editor but blank.

so whats wrong? should i even be using a linear layout?

this is roughly what its supposed to look like http://www.mediafire.com/view/?z945tz2vrb2x46t

and this is what it looks like after Abdul and Ralgha's help as well as setting the base linear layout's height to wrap content http://www.mediafire.com/view/?px17q2z3yyeo8az

Thanks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/today"
            android:src="@string/today"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/weeklylist_blocks"
            />

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>


`![screwed up layout][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about weight right now, leave it removed.  In your TextView, change "android:src" to "android:text" (without the quotes naturally).  If that alone doesn't solve it, remove the textSize line and see what happens.  If that works, then you can start playing with sizes (and weights if needed).

Also, textSize should be given in sp rather than dp.  sp is for text, dp is for everything else, though that's not what is causing your problem.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/today"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/today"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/weeklylist_blocks"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: How are you adding "Monday"?  You don't have that in your layout code above.

Comment: ya dont worry about the monday part. thats why i said it was roughly what it was supposed to look like. i just posted those shots to show you how they were supposed to be spaced

Comment: Change the android:layout_height of the LinearLayout that is inside the ScrollView to be "wrap_content".  Also, remove the first LinearLayout and make ScrollView the base, remember to move the xmlns attributes into the ScrollView.  I've edited my answer to demonstrate these and the original changes I suggested.

Comment: i dont understand. that didnt change anhything

Comment: That makes sure there's no extra space in the LinearLayout to mess things up.  I suspect it's something with the margins or padding on your ImageView.  You could try using android:adjustViewBounds or android:cropToPadding on it.  If you look at it in the graphical layout part of Eclipse it will show you the margin borders, that might help figure out the problem.

Comment: ok well i substituted the image for another one and now it has the correct borders.... so its fixed. but what would have caused that? i dont want this to happen again

Comment: The dimensions of the image.  You can play with android:scaleType on the imageview to try to make it resize correctly too.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

might be the cause of your problems

Comment: removing it did nothing. does it need to be another value?

Comment: sorry no idea - I struggle a lot with layouts too, just thought to answer as the layout_weight seems not right in place - hope somebody else can help

Comment: as you seem new here from your reputation number - dont forget to accept the answer given by Ralgha as it seems to did the trick. You accept it by clicking the tick below the number with up and down arrow. Also upvoting the correct number is normally done (clicking the up arrow)

Comment: ya.... well it only fixed half of the problem. so when its all fixed his will get the check. got it?

Comment: totally got it ;-) (didnt see there is an additional problem)

Comment: just dont discriminate cause im new. im deceptively sharp :P

Comment: I have no doubt whatsoever about that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Its works like charm, Use the following coding to achieve your thing:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/today"
        android:src="@string/today"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/today"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nissan"
        android:src="@drawable/weeklylist_blocks" />

 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hate to say it but that didnt work either... my textview appears now but with a huge margin at the top. and the image is still having the same problems

Comment: check the above links in the post. the only problem left is image one's height

Comment: @dieblazin: i am in china, mediafire website is blocked here, i can't go through that link... here many of websites is blocked... sorry...

Comment: ok well i need the text view at the very top followed immediately by the image. no gap in between them